# .toggle method is not working in java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, toggle

so i was following a tutorial on youtube on how to make a minecraft pvp client and when i followed the steps to make a test mod in minecraft that tests the input/to show something in console when you press "b" for example but when i typed in `modmanager.testMod.toggle();` eclipse said the method toggle() is undefined for type TestMod.

i changed it to .OnToggle() but it didn't work so i pressed create method "toggle()" and that didn't work either. by the way it created `public void toggle() {` in TestMod.java

Comment: Java is case sensitive. Is it testMod or TestMod? Is it actually toggle()?

Comment: it is .toggle() and idk if your talking about the command or the file but the code has testMod and TestMod is the name of the file.